# Puppet: Is it possible to set a master/client architecture without knowing my clients addressess?

Tags: linux, https, puppet, devops

Situation: I have to prepare to manage a large amount of remote servers.

Problem: They are going to be in different private networks. So I won't be able to reach them from outside, but they can easily reach my master node.

Is it sufficient that my client nodes know how to reach my master node in order for them to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. 
We have exactly that, "all in cloud" server infrastructure on multiple cloud providers, plus numbers of puppet manageable workstations on different continents and one puppet server responsible for hundreds of nodes and additional puppet dashboard server. They all communicate without any problems across Internet.
Something similar to this:
[Puppet Infrastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBMls.png)